# QSECOFR password reset

Tags: ibm, ibm-midrange

I just bought a second hand IBM iSeries 9406-250 for educational use, but I can't find the QSECOFR password.

Which ways are available to recover it if you don't have any details, except the device serial numbers/stickers on it? I need to log in at least once to fetch out the device's license keys...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Infocenter is the place for all IBM midrange information.  This link describes how to use DST to reset the QSECOFR password.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/topic/rzamh/rzamhrecover.htm

Comment: I don't have both passwords - is there another recovery procedure?

Comment: You'll need to use the physical front panel.  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzajr%2Frzajrrecoveriseries.htm

Comment: I attempted the described procedure, but if I connect to the QCONSOLE session using a TN5250 client I get disconnected immediately - is there a way to re-enable the QCONSOLE workstation-id for remote access using the front panel?

Comment: I don't have personal experience with the 250.  I think you will find some help on the midrange.com mailing list.  Thee are people there with a lot of experience with various hardware combinations.

Comment: Problem is solved now, had to use a twinax console. It was a PITA to find one, but it's fixed now. Thanks!!